# Setting up Validation via VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

Validation via VBA code does not appear

I tried to add validation to a range of cells via VBA code
It runs without error but when I open my excel worksheet the cells
do not show any validation

```
Set hoursRange = Range("G" & nextRow & ":" & ColLetter & nextRow)

With hoursRange.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=0", Formula2:="=24"
End With
```

I expect the cells in my worksheet to have the validation

Comment: Works for me (Excel 2016) when I set `nextRow=1` and `ColLetter="K"`. Did you check that `nextRow` and `ColLetter` are what you expect them to be?

Comment: when I add the script directly to the worksheet module and trigger it via a button. it worked

Comment: However i'm actually running a VBA script from another excel file that will add worksheets to the target excel

Comment: Then you will first have to get the workbook that you want to modify from the `Workbooks` collection and use `theWorkbook.Sheet("theSheet").Range(...)` to set `hoursRange`.

Comment: Ok tested again.... when i set the Range  to Range("G9). meaning i select only one cell.. it works

Comment: not sure why when i select multiple cells in a range it cannot set the validation

Comment: Different version of Excel maybe? If it only works on single cells I would just loop through the range and assign the validation to each cell individually instead of wasting time trying to figure this one out.